# ElasticSearch histogram facet exception

Tags: java, javascript, json, elasticsearch, facet

When I execute this query on my `events` index:

```
{
"query": { 
    "query_string": {
        "query": "*"
    } 
},
"facets": {
    "histo1": {
        "histogram": { 
            "key_field": "authorid",
            "value_field": "article",
            "interval": 10
        }
    }
}
}
```

I get the error:

```
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[_2jzw4DMR9mSnl5vLIK_4A][events][0]: SearchParseException[[events][0]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n\t\"query\": { \r\n\t\t\"query_string\": {\r\n\t\t\t\"query\": \"*\"\r\n\t\t} \r\n\t},\r\n\t\"facets\": {\r\n\t\t\"histo1\": {\r\n\t\t\t\"histogram\": { \r\n\t\t\t\t\"key_field\": \"authorid\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\"value_field\": \"article\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\"interval\": 10\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t}\r\n}]]]; nested: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]; }{[_2jzw4DMR9mSnl5vLIK_4A][events][2]: SearchParseException[[events][2]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n\t\"query\": { \r\n\t\t\"query_string\": {\r\n\t\t\t\"query\": \"*\"\r\n\t\t} \r\n\t},\r\n\t\"facets\": {\r\n\t\t\"histo1\": {\r\n\t\t\t\"histogram\": { \r\n\t\t\t\t\"key_field\": \"authorid\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\"value_field\": \"article\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\"interval\": 10\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t}\r\n}]]]; nested: { goes on and on this way... }
```

Both the `key_field` and the `value_field` exist.

When I leave out the `facets` part of the query, it will query successfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some sample documents in a http://sense.qbox.io/gist/?

Comment: Can you provide the full error please as the last few lines actually usually indicate what's wrong...